# « Il y en a un ou une »

Tags: accord

Cette question ne concerne pas l'usage mais une interprétation pure et rigoureuse de la grammaire.
Le pronom « en » étant neutre, je me demandais s'il était correct de dire « il y en a une », « j'en ai mangé une »… et non pas « [nom féminin], il y en a un ». La deuxième phrase sonne complètement fausse, mais je ne vois pas pourquoi « un » s'accorde alors que l'on dirait « des pommes, j'en ai pris plein ».

Comment: Sonne complètement *faux*

Comment: "Il y en a un qui [verbe] etc.." Assez comun,non?

Answer (score 1):

On dit « des pommes, j'en ai pris plein. » parce que « plein » n'est pas un adjectif mais un adverbe et les adverbes ne sont sujet à aucun accord. « un » est un pronom et les pronoms ont des formes correspondant aux genres et nombres ou en d'autre mots ils s'accordent.

> (TLfi) III. Mot inv. à valeur d'adv.
>   A. 1. [Le plus souvent sous la forme fam. tout plein] Très, beaucoup, entièrement.
>    • Aimer tout plein; tout plein gentil.
>    • Des tas de copeaux énormes, amusants tout plein (ZOLA, Assommoir, 1877, p.519).
>    • Le jour était maintenant plein levé (GIONO, Chant monde, 1934, p.195).

Comment: On dit plein parce que plein est un adverbe, mais on dit surtout pris et pas prise. Pourtant pomme est avant le verbe.

Comment: Peut-on savoir pourquoi vous parlez de plenitude? [blague] Quid de "en manger un ou en manger une?

Comment: @user8171079 « pris » est très similaire à un adjectif puisque c'est un participe passé; les deux s'accordent, sauf exception pourrait-on dire. Ici l'exception est due à « en » ; on aurait « la » à la place de « en » il y aurait accord.